# Print all rows of CSV in Python only works once

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I wrote a very simple program that was supposed to read a CSV and print all of the rows twice.  However, when I ran the program, it printed all of the rows the first time, and nothing the second time.

Code:

```
import csv

csvfile = csv.reader(open(<path>, 'rb'))

print 'Attempt 1'
for row in csvfile:
    print row

print 'Attempt 2'
for row in csvfile:
    print row
```

Output:

```
Attempt 1
['a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'f']
Attempt 2
```

Why is the code not printing the contents again the second time?

Answer (score 3):

You need to `rewind` the open file:

```
import csv

csvfile = csv.reader(open(<path>, 'rb'))

print 'Attempt 1'
for row in csvfile:
    print row

csvfile.seek(0, 0)

print 'Attempt 2'
for row in csvfile:
    print row
```

This way it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure the `csvfile` variable you create is a generator object.

Generators are not stored in memory but **can only be iterated over once**!

Hope this helps,
Luke