# Python get value based on csv column function only works for the first time

Tags: python

I have the following csv file:

```
ID  A   B
3   6   1
4   16  8
5   21  11
6   7   1
```

And I got this function to get the value based on the certain column:

```
import csv

dada1 = open("test.csv",newline='')
data2 = csv.reader(dada1)

def get_value(ID,data):
    record = 0
    for rows in data: 
        if rows[0] == ID:
            record = rows[1]
            
    return record  
    
  
get_value("5",data2) # '21'
get_value("5",data2) # '0'
```

The first time I ran the get_value function I got the correct value which is 21.
However, after I hit the same function again I received 0. I don't know what happened.

How can I improve it so each time I get 21?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37444734).

Comment: Thank you! I am looking into seek()

Comment: the seek function doesn't work with csv.reader. So I just put the input data step inside the function and it worked.

Comment: Glad you sorted it.